# Setting background image so that it's not resized (pixel-perfect)

Tags: android-layout, android

I have a `Button` with a background drawable, `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. There is no text on the button. However, its display size is such that the drawable is resized a little bit and looks blurry, unless I set width and height to those of the drawable in `px`. How can I make `wrap_content` work? Or any other way that doesn't involve hard-coding the size of button, so that I don't need to make additional edits when the size of the drawable changes?

Here's my XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/btn" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Put it in the `-nodpi` folder.

Comment: @323go: That will break my idea to have several versions of the drawable - like 64x64 for hdpi and 128x128 for xhdpi, and let Android pick the best version automatically.

Comment: You could select the correct version based on resolution yourself... but I wonder if you find yourself reverting back to allowing Android to choose (and scale).

Comment: @323go: Scaling is not an option, it totally blurs the graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Use ImageButton instead of the regular Button.  It provides access to the property `android:src` and set your image there, instead of as a background.  Background images are always fit-to-fill, where as the "source" property controls image resizing via the `android:scaleType` property.  See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

Note, for your ImageButton, you'll also need to be sure that `android:background="@null"`, otherwise you'll see the default button image behind your source image.

Edit:

Here is an updated version of your XML.  I've added a new button, above the one you started with, although I used one of my images.  The particular image is long and not that tall.  In the regular Button, it stretches to fill the widget, losing perspective.  In the new ImageButton to the top, it maintains it's perspective.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/new_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/postwall" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/new_btn"
                android:background="@drawable/postwall" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know of this. But what if I need a `ToggleButton`?

Comment: Also, your method doesn't work. I did as you said (replaced a regular Button with ImageButton with suggested parameters), and it is still stretched.

Comment: It works fine, as I have used this method on many apps.  Are you sure you're placing the image in the SOURCE ('src') location and not the BACKGROUND location?  Any images in Background will be stretched.  The difference between Button and ImageButton is that only ImageButton has the Source option.

Comment: Yep, image is `src` and `background` is `@null`. No luck. No idea why. Button has height and width set to `wrap_content`, is that correct?

Comment: Which ScaleType are you using?

Comment: So, I just want to be sure - is the problem you're having: A) that the background is scaling to fit the available ImageButton field, and thus becoming skewed, or B) the whole ImageButton field is scaling up or down depending on the size of the available space, and thus causing the OS to resize your image (but keeping it in correct perspective)?

Comment: In the particular place I'm currently practicing with it seems like A) because proportions are distorted (horizontal stretch more than vertical), but in some other places image is scaled with respect to aspect ratio.

Comment: Can you post the XML for the distorted button, along with the dimensions of the image?